# Shibboleth Choosing Authentication Mechanism Based on SP

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I am Using Shibboleth as IDP

For starters, how do i configure IDP to pick an authentication mechanism based on sp
like

SP1- Database Authentication

SP2- External Authentication

SP3- LDAP Authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can configure the behaviour required in replying party.xml

```
<bean parent="RelyingPartyByName" c:relyingPartyIds="https://sp.example.org">
    <property name="profileConfigurations">
        <list>
        <!-- Your refs or beans here. -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And

we can specify the desired authentication mechanism as

```
<bean parent="SAML2.SSO" p:authenticationFlows="#{{'Password'}}" />
```

which will be like

```
 <bean parent="RelyingPartyByName" c:relyingPartyIds="https://sp.example.org">
        <property name="profileConfigurations">
            <list>
                <bean parent="SAML2.SSO" p:authenticationFlows="#{{'Password'}}" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```